# I keep receiving an UnboundLocalError with speech_output in my alexa skill

Tags: python, python-2.7, alexa-skills-kit

I started receiving this error but it was working before so I'm not sure what changed.

> File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 126, in get_elevator_status
>   speech_output += 'On' + elevators['line'] + ' at station ' +
>   elevators['station'] + \ UnboundLocalError: local variable
>   'speech_output' referenced before assignment

```
def get_elevator_status():
    session_attributes = {}
    card_title = "Septa Elevator Status"
    should_end_session = True

    response = urllib2.urlopen(API_BASE_URL + "/elevator")
    septa_elevator_status = json.load(response)

    if septa_elevator_status['meta']['elevators_out'] == 0:
        speech_output = 'All Elevators are currently operational'
    else:
        for elevators in septa_elevator_status['results']:
            speech_output += 'On' + elevators['line'] + ' at station ' + elevators['station'] + \
                ' the ' + elevators['elevator'] + \
                ' elevator has ' + elevators['message'] + ' . '

    return build_response(session_attributes, build_speechlet_response(
        card_title, speech_output, reprompt_text, should_end_session))
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined what `speech_output` is in the else case.

`speech_output` is defined if `septa_elevator_status['meta']['elevators_out'] == 0`, but not otherwise. The else clause needs to either also define `speed_output`, or it needs to be defined before the if / else block. Bear in mind: `a += b` means `a` is whatever it was, plus `b`. So, if `a` was not defined, you'll raise an error.

Presumably, this would not have been an error before because the if case was evaluating as True which meant `speech_output` was being defined, but now the if case is not True so `speech_output` is no longer defined.

Answer (score 0):

Check the contents of `septa_elevator_status['results']`. If it is empty (presumably, that's what's happening), the code in the for loop won't execute and `speech_output` won't be defined.